# AWS DynamoDB Object Persistence Model: My class is unsupported, it cannot be instantiated

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I designed a simple class like that:

```
[DynamoDBTable("MyTableName")]
public class MySimpleClass{

    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public MySimpleClass(AnotherClass anotherClassMessage){
        this.Id = anotherClassMessage.Id;
        this.TimeStamp = anotherClassMessage.TimeStamp;
        this.Message = anotherClassMessage.Message;
    }
}
```

When I try to persist on my DynamoDB Table using a **DynamoDBContext** object *context* to convert for a DynamoDB Object Persistence Model using:

```
context.ToDocument(data)
```

it throws the exception **e** below:

**e.Message**: Type myProject.myNameSpace.MySimpleClass is unsupported, it cannot be instantiated

**e.StackTrace**: at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.StorageConfig..ctor(ITypeInfo targetTypeInfo)
at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.ItemStorageConfig..ctor(ITypeInfo targetTypeInfo)
at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.ItemStorageConfigCache.CreateStorageConfig(Type baseType, String actualTableName)
at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.ItemStorageConfigCache.GetConfig(Type type, DynamoDBFlatConfig flatConfig, Boolean conversionOnly)
at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.ObjectToItemStorage(Object toStore, Type objectType, Boolean keysOnly, DynamoDBFlatConfig flatConfig)
at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.ObjectToItemStorage[T](T toStore, Boolean keysOnly, DynamoDBFlatConfig flatConfig)
at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.ToDocument[T](T value, DynamoDBOperationConfig operationConfig)
at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.ToDocument[T](T value)
at myProject4PersistanceOnDynamo.DynamoTableWrapper.Persist[T](T data) in C:\MyProject\myProject4PersistanceOnDynamo\DynamoTableWrapper.cs:line 101 (which means **context.ToDocument(data)**)

**e.Source**: AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2 (Version: 3.3.0.0 | Running version: v4.0.30319)

My myProject4PersistanceOnDynamo.DynamoTableWrapper.Persist[T](T data) is:

```
public void Persist<T>(T data)
{
    // Client is a AmazonDynamoDBClient object with correct credentials
    private DynamoDBContext context = new DynamoDBContext(Client)

    try
    {
        var doc = context.ToDocument(data);
        Table.PutItem(doc);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I checked the documentation on this [page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKHighLevel.html) and this [other page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DeclarativeTagsList.html) and it doesn't seems I used a forbbiden object. Any idea what wrong is going on?

Comment: Wild guess here (I don't use C#). Could it be because the class doesn't have a simple constructor with id, message, and timestamp so it can't be instantiated from those values alone?

Comment: We had this happen as well. And we had a parameterless constructor. The issue, for us, was that we had a property, on the model, defined as object, and it was really a string. When we changed it from object to string, it worked.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> public MySimpleClass(AnotherClass anotherClassMessage){

You need to have a constructor without any dependencies.

Define a polymorphic constructor like this,

```
public MySimpleClass() {}
```

that should solve the problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect! thank you! That's a subtle detail. I am trying to find it written on documentation.

Comment: If that solves your problem, please take is as answered, if you still have issues please leave a comment.

Comment: Hey @Kannaiyan do you mind explaining why we need that constructor? That solved my problem too.

Comment: When you try to persist it tries to re-construct the object, before sending it to the storage pipeline, dropping any unwanted data from your object and expects a empty ctor.